# How to loop through json with button and js

Tags: javascript, json, http

I failed to write js code, which shows one element of json array after another on the html page after clicking the button.

I receive words from DB on local server in json format.
This is my http request which returns json and tries to count how many items this json has (to make the button understand, that after clicking more times than the actual number of items in json the js code must start showing words from the beginning):

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
var method = 'GET';
var url = 'data.php';
var asynchronous = true;

ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
ajax.send();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState ==  4 && this.status == 200)
    { 
        var words = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
      //  alert(this.responseText);
        console.log(words);
    //  console.log(words[0].word_item);
         var i, j
     for ( i  in words){
         console.log(words[i].word_item);   
     }
     var arrayLenth = words.length;
     console.log(arrayLenth);    
     return arrayLenth;

        }
    }
```

This is json array I receive:

```
    0
    :
    {id: "1", word_item: "house"}
    1
    :
    {id: "26", word_item: "architecto"}
    2
    :
    {id: "27", word_item: "tenetur"}
    3
    :
    {id: "28", word_item: "Adipisci"}
    4
    :
    {id: "29", word_item: "provident"}
    5
    :
    {id: "30", word_item: "tenetur"}
```

This is my js buttom counter.

```
var clicks = 0;
    function clickCount(){
        do   { 
            clicks ++;
            console.log(clicks);
            document.getElementById('place').innerHTML=clicks;
                if (clicks >=6) {
                    clicks=0;
                };      
            }
        while (clicks>=7);
                            }
```

In line ' if (clicks >=6)' I would like to see not '6', but variable which containes the length of my json, but all attempts were in vain.

This is html page:

```
<body>
 <button onClick='clickCount()'>Жми</button>
<div id = 'place'></div>
```

What can i do to fix that?

The expected result is the following:

- Js button counter gets the length of the received json array
- I see one element of json array one after another by clicking on the button. When there are more button clicks than the length of the array the counter starts from the zero element and shows the elements of json array from the beginnig.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the solution is something like this:

```js
const jsonArr = [
  { id: 0, field: "value" },
  { id: 1, field: "value2" },
  { id: 2, field: "value3" }
];

initializeButton(jsonArr);

function initializeButton(arr) {
  let counter = 0;
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let element = arr[counter];
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(element);
    counter = (counter + 1) % arr.length;
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click here</button>
<output id="output"></output>
```

In your code you should put something like this:

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var words = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    initializeButton(words);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine! I just need to access the word_item, but I'm sure I can do it by myself. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Simply instead of `JSON.stringify(element)` you can access individual property as `element.word_item`.